# Ideal of Ring $R$ where $R$ is finite or countably infinite.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $R$ be a ring with a proper ideal $I$ such that $|R|$ is finite or infinite. If $R$ is finitely generated, then there exists ideal $J$ s.t. $$ R = I\times J $$

This is right ? If not, please give me an example. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Since "such that $|R|$ is either finite or infinite" is not a very useful condition, I suspect you accidentally left something out, possibly something you mentioned in your title... do you mean "finite or countably infinite"? And, since rings with unity are finitely generated over themselves, are we to assume that this question is about rings not necessarily having identity? Or did you intend $I$ to be finitely generated?

Comment: If $R$ is finite or countably infinite and $R$ is finitely generated, for example ${\bf Z}\times {\bf Z}_p$, then is it possible that $I$ is not finitely generated ?

Comment: What does "$R$ is finitely generated" mean? Usually this is a condition on modules or algebras.

Comment: Here I mean that $R$ is abelian group under addition which is finitely generated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try thinking about this with $R = \mathbb{Z}$ and $I = (2)$. What would you take for $J$?

As requested, another counter-example is $\mathbb{C}[x]$. Let $I = (f(x))$ and $J=(g(x))$ be any ideals, then $I \cap J \neq 0$ since it contains $f(x)g(x)$.

Comment: You are right. If we do not consider the case where $I$ is an ideal of ${\bf Z}\subset R$, what happen ?

Comment: Are you asking for a different counter-example? I would like to understand the purpose.

Comment: Yes. I mean that I want different counterexample.